# Unable to retrieve a timestamp in UTC from mysql with PDO and php

Tags: php, pdo, timestamp, timezone

I have a table with a column named 'timestamp' of type 'timestamp' with default = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and attribute = ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
At the start of my web page code I have date_default_timezone_set("UTC"} and in my database connection I've added a setup parameter = [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET time_zone = '+00:00'".
If run the statement:  $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); anywhere in my code, the current UTC date time is shown.
However, whenever a record is retrieved from the database with a SELECT query, the timestamp field always shows the local (in my case, pacific) time.

How can I get a timestamp from a database in UTC time.
My understanding is that mysql stores timestamps as UTC, and converts to local time on display.  Since I have the timezone set to UTC in code, php.ini and the database, I'm not sure why local time is being shown.
I'm obviously missing something.
I'm using mysql 5.7.36, php 8.1.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: A timestamp has no timezone and is per definition always UTC. And it is _not_ a datetime!

Comment: I understand that timestamp are UTC.  What I don't understand is,  if the current timestamp is 2023-03-26 23:37:19 when a new row is saved to the database, why does it display as 2023-03-26 16:21:10 when it is retrieved, even though I've set my database and php time zone to UTC.

Comment: Why don;t you change your column type to datetime to avoid that hassle?

Comment: I want to track changes to the data and the on update current_timestamp seemed a nice feature.  I need to synchronize data in different databases and a UTC timestamp seemed a nice way to do this.

Comment: You could just use the MySQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function, to avoid ambiguity?  It would retrieve the numeric timestamp, which you could then format in PHP however you wish

Comment: Honk der Hase's comment that UTC is not a time zone, caused me to remove my attempts to set the global and session time zones, and allow the SYSTEM time zone to exist.  Then Rob Eyre's suggestion solved my problem. Many thanks to all.